# ¿Por qué a la cuchara, tenedor, etc, se les llama "cubiertos"?

Tags: etimología, historia

Según [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuberter%C3%ADa):

> Hasta el siglo XV se sabe que se "comía a cubierto" haciendo referencia siempre al mantel que se ponía sobre la mesa para mostrar a los comensales que se había tomado toda precaución contra el envenenamiento, *cubriéndolos*, de aquí el origen de la palabra.

Esta explicación es muy confusa. ¿Cubriendo qué cosa? ¿En qué sentido era una precaución contra el envenenamiento?

¿Alguien tiene más detalles sobre el origen de esta expresión, o puede explicar en detalle el significado del párrafo de arriba?

Answer (score 6):

La explicación es realmente confusa. Parece ser una mala copia de un párrafo que se encuentra en inglés en un libro, [Food and Beverage Service](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=2EJ1BAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT258&ots=-vRzN_REQ5&dq=cutlery%20was%20covered%20poisoning%20xv%20century&pg=PT258#v=onepage&q=cutlery%20was%20covered%20poisoning%20xv%20century&f=false); pego una captura de pantalla:

[image]

Lo que dice es que en inglés hay un término técnico en la industria del servicio de comida, *cover*, que puede referirse a un juego de cubiertos, y que se origina en la costumbre de servir "bajo cubierto". Esto es, se cubrían los platos con una gran servilleta blanca para indicar que se habían tomado todas las precauciones posibles para evitar que los comensales se intoxicaran. Si esto es correcto, no se habla de los cubiertos en sí, pero se entiende que la misma servilleta podría cubrirlos también.

El resto parece una confusión al traducir del inglés al español. El mantel cubría la mesa, no los platos y cubiertos; el objetivo de la servilleta era señalar el cuidado puesto en el servicio, pero obviamente no era garantía de nada; y el término inglés *poisoning* en este caso debería ser traducido como "intoxicación", no como "envenenamiento", que en español suena a intencional.

De todas formas esto sólo aclara la fuente de lo que dice el artículo de Wikipedia. La explicación suena verosímil como origen del término *cubierto* en español, pero no tenemos certeza de que sea así.

Answer (score 3):

Pongo por aquí la definición de la palabra en 1729 por parte del *Autoridades*:

> CUBIERTO. s.m. El servicio de mesa que se pone à cada uno de los que han de comer, y se compone de plato, cuchillo, chuchár, tenedor, pan y servilleta: y porque esta se pone encima de todo se llamó Cubierto.

Resulta curioso que originalmente se llamara *cubierto* a todo, incluyendo el plato y el pan; y porque la servilleta se ponía cubriendo todo se llamó a todo así. Luego ya la definición de *cubierto* pasó a ser la del conjunto de cuchillo, tenedor y cuchara. Entiendo, pues, que en el texto que mencionas en tu pregunta, se dice que el mantel (el individual, es decir, la servilleta) cubría a los cubiertos y por eso se llaman así, aunque ciertamente el texto no queda muy claro.

He buscado la palabra en diccionarios anteriores. En el *Covarrubias* de 1611 se hace mención al *cubierto* como el acobertor, el paño con que se cubre la cama. Y en otros diccionarios se traduce *cubierto* como *covered*, como en el Percival de 1591.

Su uso, en todo caso, se atestigua anteriormente:

> *Volví los ojos hacia la puerta, y veo entrar un cubierto muy majestuoso. Pusiéronle en la mesa y dijo el hombre: 'Ésta es la muestra del escabeche que tengo para esta Cuaresma, y como no es más de muestra, es poco.'*
>
> Juan de Zabaleta, "El día de fiesta por la tarde", 1660 (España).

Answer (score 2):

El origen de la palabra es la palabra latina "coopertus". Otro tema es el significado. En el Diccionario de la Academia (1729) ya se recoge la acepción. El origen más plausible viene de la época de la Ilustración, donde se tenía por costumbre el cubrir los servicios de mesa (platos, cubiertos...) para indicar que se habían tomado todas las precauciones posibles, ya que por entonces era relativamente frecuente la práctica del envenenamiento durante las comidas.

De la costumbre de cubrir a lo que hoy llamamos "cubiertos", les quedó ese nombre.

[Enlace 1](http://www.elcastellano.org/palabra/cubierto)

[Enlace 2](https://definiciona.com/cubierto/)

[Enlace 3](http://eloutletdelamesa.com/blog/origen-de-los-cubiertos/)

Answer (score 1):

La definición de lo que hoy llamamos "cubiertos", debe tener algo en común con el francés "couverts" con idéntico significado. También en catalán "coberts".
Pero hay que recordar que el tenedor (de dos dientes) hace su aparición en algunas mesas de la nobleza Europea, procedente de Venecia, hacia 1730/60, pero no se generaliza en casas particulares, ni en las tabernas, ventas o fondas, hasta tiempos de desarrollo industrial, que permitió producir tenedores de cuatro dientes en serie, por estampación o forjado. Es decir, que el tenedor aparece en la mesas de burgueses, trabajadores o campesinos, ya bien avanzado el 1800.
Antes del tenedor, siempre hubo cuchillos para las carnes, que en general cada persona tenía el suyo. De ahí; en Inglés es "Cutlery".
Por supuesto, también solía haber una cuchara de madera para los potajes y sopas.
En conclusión, lo de "cubiertos" sigue siendo para mi de oscuro origen: No lo sé. Pero tampoco me parecen muy aceptables las propuestas anteriores